# Get Type of the properties of a data class Type in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, reflection

Let's say I have the following function in Kotlin

```
fun getPropertyTypes(dataClassType: Type): List<Type> {

}
```

And the Type of returnType is a data class in my project. How do I then get the Type of the properties of that data class?

```
data class ProjectDataClass(
    val pdPropertyResponse: MyResponseClass,
    val pdPropertyError: MyErrorClass,
)
```

Comment: You could start to read [official documentation about reflection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reflection.html). What platform are you aiming ? JVM ? Do you want it to work recursively ?